# How can I add a context menu for an entire row of a WPF grid?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have some controls in a WPF grid (not a data grid). I would like to add a context menu for an entire row of the grid. I have tried adding the context menu to the RowDefinition but that doesn't seem to work. I also tried adding a border or rectangle over the entire row, with background set to transparent, and the context menu on that. That works but then I can't interact with the controls behind it.

Here's my sample XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Some Property" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Actual" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Setpoint" />
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="Set" />
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Another Property" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Actual" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="Setpoint" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Content="Set" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Should the Context menu also appear for items in the row ? Like the TextBox ? Normally TextBox has it's own ContextMenu

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Yes, I want to override any existing ContextMenus for all items in the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the Context Menu Static:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
       <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContext">
          <MenuItem Header="Test"/>
          <MenuItem Header="Test 1"/>
          <MenuItem Header="Test 2"/>
       </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    //Extra border added
    <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Background="Transparent" ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContext}"/>

    // ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContext}" added
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Some Property" ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContext}"/>

    // ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContext}" added
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Actual" ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContext}"/>

    // ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContext}" added
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Setpoint" ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContext}"/>

    // ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContext}" added
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="Set" ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContext}"/>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Another Property" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="Actual" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="Setpoint" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Content="Set" />
</Grid>
```

I have also added an extra border to cover the rest of the row.

Comment: Good solution, but I'd rather register for the PreviewMouseDownEvent only to the transparent border. No need to bind the menu to any of the elements. That's the most reliable way to override the hosted controls' context menu.